# How to Create Spring Data Aggregate Query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to Spring-Data-Mongo. I have created following query for getting birthday count from each month. Can anyone help me to convert in Spring Data aggreate query.

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate( 
[
    { $group: 
        { _id: { month: { $month: "$birthDate" }, }, 
            count: { $sum:1 }, 
            date: { $first: "$birthDate" } 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        $project: 
        { 
            month: 
            { 
                $dateToString: { format: "%m", date: "$date" } 
            }, 
            count: 1, 
            _id: 0 
        } 
    }])
```

Here what I have tried so far however it's not giving output what I want.

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.group("month1").first("birthDate").as("date").count().as("count"),
            Aggregation.project("_id").and("date").dateAsFormattedString("%m").as("month").and("count").as("count").andExpression("month(date)").as("month1")
```

Comment: I find it helpful when building aggregate queries in Spring Data Mongo to log the raw MongoDB queries that Spring Data is generating. You can do this by setting the following property `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG`

Comment: If you don't want to project _id field (`_id:0`), you should try `project().andExclude("_id")` instead of `project("_id")`